# How to call destroy on a component from inside the component?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have a modal component and I want to be able to destroy it when the user clicks on the x button, I also have a notification popup that  destroys itself after  an  interval but  I'd like to give the user the ability to close it with the x button too.
I know I can pass an event to the component but I think it'll be better if the component is self destructive.
Also there might be a better design for such case but that's the way  I thought about it, other pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: to illustrate more, something like this.destroy() maybe?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If by destruction you mean node removal from the DOM, then all you need to do is obtain a reference to the top-most element in your component using Svelte's `bind:this` and remove said element using `Node.removeChild()`:

```js
<script>
  let nodeRef
</script>

<div bind:this={nodeRef}>
  <h3>Hey I'm a component</h3>
  <button on:click={() => nodeRef.parentNode.removeChild(nodeRef)}>
    Remove me :(
  </button>
</div>
```

[Demo REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/22d8c178f6434874b9c281bb6041d286?version=3.23.0)

#### Edit

I had missed the point about suggesting a different approach. Since the display of the modal or notification will be triggered by the parent component (be it from a user action or as a programmatic response), it feels more natural to me that the parent would handle the dismissal of the modal or notification as well.

You don't have to use events to handle closing a modal or notification, you can simply pass a close handler as a prop. This will also save you from having to handle node removal yourself (or node create/append for that matter).

Something like the following would be more 'Svelte-like':

**App.svelte**

```js
<script>
  import MyModal from './MyModal.svelte'

  let showModal = false
</script>

<div>
  {#if showModal}
    <MyModal onClose={() => showModal = false} />
  {/if}
  <button on:click={() => showModal = true}>Show Modal</button>
</div>
```

**MyModal.svelte**

```js
<script>
  export let onClose
</script>

<div>
  <h3>Hi I'm a modal <span on:click={onClose}>X</span></h3>
</div>
```

[Demo 2 REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/582ebe32411a44e1824d0b250c53085b?version=3)

Comment: Thank you, I was  using the 2nd approach but felt there might be a better one, happy to know that I haven't went far off with my thinking.

Comment: Note that if your modal/notification component is not a direct child of the parent handling the display/dismissal logic, it might be worth using a store to hold the `showModal` or `showNotification` boolean so that you don't have to pass down a close handler through several layers of nested components.

Comment: gotcha! of course will keep that in mind, I'll just try to put myself in a position where I won't have to use stores for UI, only data  :)

Comment: I hear you, and I generally agree, but it's not always possible (or desirable) to keep these components as direct children, and frankly, in these situations, having a single store dedicated to tracking UI state is a very simple and efficient solution. Good luck with your dev! :)

Comment: I'm suspicious of this because onDestroy isn't called. Please see your updated Demo 1 REPL console logs https://svelte.dev/repl/49dc7605f26c4b32939d1223317158b2?version=3.23.0

Comment: Suspicious as in I think this leaks memory (until garbage collected).

Comment: @n-smits that `onDestroy` isn't called is not surprising as we're manipulating the DOM directly instead of delegating to Svelte to trigger a re-render (and thus benefit from life cycle hooks, among them `onDestroy`) as is the case in the 2nd approach (which is the favored one if you read through my answer, notably because it is cleaner, as in I'm expecting Svelte-generated code to do a better job handling object destruction and garbage collection).

Comment: I've read it, but it isn't what I'm looking for (removing the component from within itself, at least without massive complication). I've read somewhere on github from Harris (creator of Svelte) there is no way to do it, but haven't looked deeper into this yet.

Answer (score 4):

[Update 2023]
Also `component.$destroy()` can be used as shown here in this link (which triggers the onDestroy events):

https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api-$destroy

And if you want to get the reference to any component within itself you can import the `get_current_component()` function from `svelte/internal` and do:

```js
import {get_current_component} from 'svelte/internal'
const THISComponent = get_current_component()

function destroySelf(){
   THISComponent.$destroy();
}
```

Don't forget you can use the `get_current_component()` only in the component initilization meaning it has to be on top level of a component (not in any functions or other declerations)

Comment: I wonder why they chose the snake case for internal functions in a JS/TS context.

Comment: Throws an error in new versions of Svelte :/ https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/9189

Answer (score 0):

**A real solution without unstable/discouraged internal APIs.**

(but just works for the case of custom elements, i.e. when you compile the svelte into web-components),, I added a potential fix for the normal case below.

```
someChildReference.getRootNode().host
```

Full example:

```
<svelte:options customElement="afkar-sv-modal" />

<script lang="typescript">

    let dialog; // HTMLDialogElement

    $: if (dialog) dialog.showModal();
</script>   

<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events a11y-no-noninteractive-element-interactions -->

<dialog
    bind:this={dialog}
    on:click|self={() => 
    {
        dialog.close();
        dialog.getRootNode().host.remove();
    }}
>
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-no-static-element-interactions -->
    <div on:click|stopPropagation>
        <slot name="header" />
        <hr />
        <slot />
        <hr />
        <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-autofocus -->
    </div>
</dialog>

<style>
    dialog {
        max-width: 64em;
        border-radius: 0.2em;
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    dialog::backdrop {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    dialog > div {
        padding: 1em;
    }
    dialog[open] {
        animation: zoom 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.56, 0.64, 1);
    }
    @keyframes zoom {
        from {
            transform: scale(0.95);
        }
        to {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
    dialog[open]::backdrop {
        animation: fade 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    @keyframes fade {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    button {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

---

You don'e use web-components compilation?
If you still want to use the normal Svelte component, I think the below way might work, not tested tho, and it needs to have data proxied through the modal parent

for Modal.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let thisRef;
    onCloseClicked = ()=>thisRef.remove();
</script>
...
```

and Parent.svelte:

```
// I assume you have the Modale.svelet defined and imported, and this is the caller of Modal
<script>
    let modal;
</script>
<Modal bind:this={modal}  thisRef={modal} />
```

---

***Side note**, I didn't find an answer that satisfies me for my usage -case, so I registered in stackoverflow to answer this as my first post:-)*