# Remove Component after time itself from DOM

Tags: javascript, svelte

Hello Guy's so I've created in Svelte a Component, which  should itself remove after a time.

```
    <script>
    export let time;
</script>

<div class="notif">
  </div>

<style>
    
    
</style>
```

How would I archive that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the consuming/parent component's responsibility of unmounting the component instead?

Comment: where can I see how to unmount the component?

Comment: This might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62126621/how-to-call-destroy-on-a-component-from-inside-the-component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3089

> The difference in Svelte 3 is that component's can't self-destruct — there's no equivalent of this.destroy(). If a component can't destroy itself, that implies that some parent or controller must destroy it, ...

To destroy the component either an `{#if}` block could be used or calling [`component.$destroy()`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api-$destroy)

A [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4c606ae5efae4eb8b8ac0e57320b2d43?version=3.46.4) with the examples

```
<script>
    import Comp1 from './Comp1.svelte'
    import Comp2 from './Comp2.svelte'

    let showComp = true

    let compRef
</script>

{#if showComp}
<Comp1 bind:showComp time={1500} />
{/if}

<Comp2 bind:this={compRef} self={compRef} time={1500}/>
```

###### Comp1

```
<script>
    import {onDestroy} from 'svelte'

    export let showComp, time

    setTimeout(() => {
        showComp = false
    }, time)

    onDestroy(() => {
        console.log('successfully destroyed Comp1')
    })

</script>

COMP 1
```

###### Comp2

```
<script>
    import {onDestroy} from 'svelte'
    
    export let self, time

    setTimeout(() => {
        self.$destroy()
    }, time)

    onDestroy(() => {
        console.log('successfully destroyed Comp2')
    })
</script>

COMP 2
```